# How to prove $\int_Xexp(-\frac12X'AX)dX=(2\pi)^\frac{n}2{\lvert{A}\rvert}^{-\frac12}$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I was studying a solution to a problem and this result was given without any explanation:

If $X\sim{N}(0,I_n)$ & A is a symmetric positive definite matrix,

$$
\int_X\exp\left(-\frac12X'AX\right)dX=(2\pi)^\frac{n}2{\lvert{A}\rvert}^{-\frac12}
$$

How can I prove this proposition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prove this by means of the eigendecomposition of your matrix. Since your matrix is symmetric positive definite, you can write $\textbf{A} = \textbf{UDU}^{T}$ with the diagonal $\textbf{D}=\textrm{diag}\left(d_1\cdots d_n\right)$ and $\mathbf{U}$ an orthogonal matrix ($\mathbf{UU}^T=\mathbf{U}^T\mathbf{U}=\mathbf{I}$). With this your integral becomes:

$$I=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp\left\{-\frac{\pmb{x}\cdot\textbf{UDU}^T\cdot\pmb{x}}{2}\right\} \,\textrm{d}\pmb{x}$$

You can now substitute $\pmb{z} = \textbf{U}^T\pmb{x}$ which is nothing more than a rotation. This gives you directly:

$$I=\prod_{i=1}^n \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left\{-\frac{d_i z_i^2}{2}\right\} \,\textrm{d}z_i = \prod_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{d_i}}$$

and since $d_1\cdot\ldots\cdot d_n = |\mathbf{A}|$, you get the desired result. The last integral, is the Gaußian integral.